# Dynamic query using hibernate criteria api

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I want to build a query dynamically using hibernate criteria api.i am facing problem with "Order By".suppose i have a statement like this

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class); 
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("price"));
```

now i want to control "asc" or "desc" based on user input.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Criteria Object API provides the Order class as the main API to manage sorting.The Order class has two methods to set the sorting order:

**asc(String attribute)** : Sorts the query by attribute in **ascending order**.

**desc(String attribute)** : Sorts the query by attribute in **descending order**.

> Now  if you want to control "asc" or "desc" based on user input then you can do the following

Let assume user input can be "asc" or "desc".

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class); 

    if (userInput.equals("asc")) {
            crit.addOrder(Order.asc("price"));
        } else if (userInput.equals("desc")) {
            crit.addOrder(Order.desc("price"));
        }
```